# php, deleting files from a cell phone

Tags: php, file-upload, mobile-devices

I am working on a project were users will be uploading images from their cell phones to the website, and I am wanting to delete these files off their phones once the images have been uploaded.

Comment: It would be really scary if the telephone allowed that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way of doing what you ask is to create your own app for the cell phones and let that upload files to the server. The app can then (if allowed by the phone os) delete the uploaded images.

Depending on the overall project, this may be or may not be worth doing.

Comment: Damn, it is pretty much required for the project.